# Display image from API In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display an image from my API. The code I am using so far does not seem to work, in the src of the image it shows just the string not the image i.e `<img src="{data.home[0].image}" alt="image">`.

My code so far is:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import '../main/main.css';

  class Main extends Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
              name: 'React',
              awsApiData: [],
          };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
          console.log('app mounted');
          /*global fetch */
          fetch('https://onelbip0e6.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/livestage/xxxx')
              .then(data => data.json())
              .then(data => this.setState({ awsApiData: data }, () => console.log(data)));
      }

      render() {
          const data = this.state.awsApiData;
          return (
              <div className="main-content container">
           {(data && data.home) &&
              <div><h2>{data.home[0].title}</h2><br /><p>{data.home[0].body}</p>
              <img src="{data.home[0].image}" alt="image"></img>
              </div>
          }    
      </div>
          );
      }
  }
  export default Main;
```

Comment: Can you try changing ```src="{data.home[0].image}"``` to ```src={data.home[0].image}``` .. Remove double quotes around the curly brackets..

Comment: That worked, cant believe it was the speech marks, Can you add answer and I can mark as correct

Comment: `" "` is always a string. `{}` is JSX syntax for a javascript expression. To use a variable within JSX you must use the `{}` syntax, and not from within a string.

Comment: @Sole, Answer has been added added..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning the value of string to img `src` so it will give the output as string only.

You need to use curly braces to embed a JavaScript expression in an attribute.

So try changing

`<img src="{data.home[0].image}" alt="image">`

**to** (Remove the quotes around curly `{}` brackets)

`<img src={data.home[0].image} alt="image">`

> Don’t put quotes around curly braces when embedding a JavaScript
>   expression in an attribute. You should either use quotes (for string
>   values) or curly braces (for expressions), but not both in the same
>   attribute.

[**Reference Link here..**](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please post your api response as well.

See if changing `src="{data.home[0].image}" to src={data.home[0].image}` helps