# JSX not outputing string in curly braces

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am using JSX to try and output a string inside a check like this...

```
 {image &&
     <img src="{image}" />
 }
```

I am expecting to have the stores `image` string output but instead I get `{image}`

I have tried with double curly braces and still get the same output.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is a proper way `src={image}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60622273/7785337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the src to the literal String `{image}`, not the value of it. Remove the quotes, ie

```html
<img src={image} />
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
<img src={image} />
```